# Cygwin copy directory with wrong name

Tags: cygwin, cp

I create a little script to copy a directory.
Sadly, cygwin do not copy the name of the directory, but instead copy all the content in a directory called `·`(it's an intepunct, not a dot en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct ).
There are no problems to execute all the commands directly in the terminal!
Anyone has ideas?

this is the script:

```
cp -r //REMOTE-PC/folder1/folder2/folder-to-copy/ ./local-folder/folder-to-copy/
```

thanks

Comment: Are you sure ? `.` is the local directory. You can not create a directory with `.` as name

Comment: @matzeri it's an intepunct, not a dot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpunct

Comment: You mentioned a script - what kind of script?  It would  be helpful if you would post the contents.

Comment: Also make sure yor script has *nix line endings, i.e. LF only, not windows line endings, i.e. CRLF. Use `dos2unix FILE` or `d2u FILE` to convert. Use an editor that can create new  files with LF line endings and will preserve LF line endings in existing files

Comment: @DougHenderson Thanks man! This solved my problem!